# Are schedules part of Indian constitution?

Tags: constitution, india

I was looking at a PDF of [India's Constitution](http://lawmin.nic.in/olwing/coi/coi-english/coi-4March2016.pdf) and started wondering about some of its details.

One thing that confused me was ~200 pages of SCHEDULES section. Are they actually officially part of Constitution? Or just published together?

Answer (score 3):

Any schedule, appendix or annex that is attached to the constitution is part of the constitution and hence binding. The naming of part of the document as a "schedule", "annex" or "appendix" doesn't make it any less integral to the document. This follows usual contract law.

The schedules contain various lists, such as a list of the states and union territories, the various forms of oath that can be used. Lists of tribal areas and provisions for their adminsitration. Lists of powers of municipalities. And so on.